# How to update with using values from row above or below

Tags: sql, sql-server

SQL Server Question:
I have data in a table that might look like this:

```
Row Group Value  
1   a     0    
2   a     545    
3   a     898    
4   a     787    
5   b     654    
6   b     438    
7   b     0    
8   c     0    
9   c     889    
10  c     551    
11  c     0    
12  c     0
```

I want to upate rows where the value = 0. The rules are - 
if the value of first row of the group (i.e. group = a row = 1) = 0 then update the value with the next value of that group i.e. row 2 value = 545. This rule only applies to the first row of the group and it must = 0.

If the value of any other row in the group (i.e. group = b row = 6) = 0 then update with the previous value <> 0 in that group until all values are <> 0 working down the list for the group.

I wanted to do this without loops/cursors etc. Anyone see a way? Thanks.

Final result should look like this:

```
Row Group Value    
1   a     545    
2   a     545    
3   a     898    
4   a     787    
5   b     654    
6   b     438    
7   b     438    
8   c     889    
9   c     889    
10  c     551    
11  c     551    
12  c     551
```

Comment: which version of sql server are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE t_base
  SET [Value] = COALESCE(t_prev.[Value], t_next.[Value], t_base.[Value]) 
FROM MyTable t_base
CROSS APPLY (
  SELECT TOP 1 [Value]
  FROM MyTable
  WHERE [Group] = t_base.[Group]
    AND [Row] < t_base.[Row]
    AND [Value] <> 0
  ORDER BY [Row] DESC
) t_prev
CROSS APPLY (
  SELECT TOP 1 [Value]
  FROM MyTable
  WHERE [Group] = t_base.[Group]
    AND [Row] > t_base.[Row]
    AND [Value] <> 0
  ORDER BY [Row] ASC
) t_next
```

Comment: Thank you! You provided the missing elements to my clumsy attempt.